# Java int formating?

Tags: java, string, integer, java-time, localtime

I want the user to input hours and minutes for a Local.Time from 00 to 23 and from 00 to 59, I scanned this as an int. It works but for values from 00 to 09 the int ignores the 0 and places then as a 0,1,2...9 instead of 00,01,02,03...09; this breaks the Local.Time since, for example "10:3"; is not a valid format for time.

I have read I can format this as a String, but I don't think that helps me since I need an int value to build the LocalTime and subsequent opperations with it.

There is a way of formatting this while kepping the variable as an int??
Can I code this differently to bypass this??
Am I wrong about how these classes work??

I am pretty new to these concepts

Here is the code I am using

```
int hours;
int minutes;

System.out.println("Input a number for the hours (00-23): ");
hours = scan.nextInt();

System.out.println("Input a number for the minutes (00-59): ");
minutes = scan.nextInt();

LocalTime result = LocalTime.parse(hours + ":" + minutes);
```

I tried using the NumberFormat class but it returns an error when trying to declare its variables (something like it is an abstract variable and cannot be instanced)

I also tried using the String format but I don't really know what to do with that string after that, it asks me for a int and not a string to build this method

Comment: Why not use `LocalTime.of(int hour, int minute)` instead of `parse`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#of-int-int-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: an `int` doesn't differentiate between 09 and 9. They are the same value: the number nine.

Next: if you already have numbers, then going back to a string to produce a date is an anti-pattern: you are *losing* type checking by this. So instead of using `LocalTime.parse` and constructing the input from `int` values, you should simply [use `LocalTime.of(hours, minutes)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#of(int,int)):

```
LocalTime result = LocalTime.of(hours, minutes);
```

Comment: This is the most simple and frankly I don't know what I was ussing parse, I just saw it somewhere else; what is the intent of the parse method then? is just to use it with a formatter?

Comment: `parse` makes sense when you already get a `String` from somewhere, for example in some JSON API. It's just another tool in the box: it's not bad, but each tool has specific situations where it's the best choice. `parse` just happened to be the wrong choice for your specific situation.

Comment: Some other users in some other situation might prefer to enter the time as `10:03` or even `10:3` rather than two numbers after each other. In that case use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:m")` and the two-arg `LocalTime.parse(CharSequence, DateTimeFormatter)` method (explained better in [azro’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74653463/5772882)).

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr** Use `LocalTime.of(hours, minutes)`, it's most straight-forward

**Alternative:** Parse with a suitable `DateTimeFormatter`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // single-digit example values
    int hours = 9;
    int minutes = 1;
    // define a formatter that parses single-digit hours and minutes
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:m");
    // use it as second argument in LocalTime.parse
    LocalTime result = LocalTime.parse(hours + ":" + minutes, dtf);
    // see the result
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

```
09:01
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Fix

- use the proper `DateTimeFormatter`

  ```
  LocalTime.parse(hours + ":" + minutes, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:m"));
  ```
- Build the expected default format

  ```
  LocalTime.parse(String.format("%02d:%02d", hours, minutes));
  ```

---

#### Improve

Use a more appropriate method

```
LocalTime.of(hours, minutes);
```